# php mail() not working on a server

Tags: php, email, phplist

I have a little issue with the php mail() function on my server. It just won't work at all. I used simple script like this

```
<?php
$to      = 'myownemail@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'test title';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: admin@thisdomainlistedontheserver.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: admin@thisdomainlistedontheserver.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else{
    echo "FAIL";
}
?>
```

I've installed PHPList on this server, and all of the functionality seems to be fine. I could send test email smoothly from my PHPList installation. So I thought it might have nothing to do with the sendmail configuration, instead, there's probably something wrong with my code.

But then I tested my simple script on my other server. Turned out it works just fine. I was getting confused at this stage. So what part is faulty here? is it my code or is it the mail server configuration?

where's the good place to start tracking the problem?

**UPDATE**

I finally got the priviledge to access the mail log... on /var/log/mail.log, I got plenty of this line

`panther5 postfix/postdrop[4961]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory`

I don't have any idea what kind of error is that? any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Are you working on your pc?

Comment: I would start by finding the logs for both PHP and sendmail and seeing if they have any errors. After that, check your spam folder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHPLists; are you sending through their server (and not using a local `sendmail`)? Usually these campaign systems use their own setup, so they can mitigate spam and other issues these types of setups face.

Comment: Here's the source for the PHPList [`phplist::sendMail()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/phplist/code/3500/tree/trunk/phplist/phplist.php#l301) method, which does appear to use `sendmail`. Hmm.

Comment: What are the servers configuration details? OS?

Comment: Take a look at the [*Message sending options*](http://sourceforge.net/p/phplist/code/3500/tree/trunk/phplist/public_html/lists/config/config.php#l504) block in `config.php`. Note the reference to `phpMailer` and lines [`519`, `523`, `527`, and `531-532`](http://sourceforge.net/p/phplist/code/3500/tree/trunk/phplist/public_html/lists/config/config.php#l519). Do you have any settings here, maybe pointing at an external SMTP host?

Comment: @klevismiho: nope... I'm working directly on the server
@MrGlass: too bad I haven't got the privilege to access the log... still asking from the server admin
@JaredFarrish: nope... I installed the PHPList on the server, and it's surely using local sendmail. I've also checked the reference of phpmailer on my phplist config file, I set it to `define("PHPMAILER",0)`, so that the PHPlist doesn't use PHPMailer class and just use simple php mail function instead
@didierc: the OS is ubuntu, it's a usual LAMP stack

Answer (score 0):

try without **"$header"**. Most likely there is an issue with header acceptability on server.
Also, some servers take email address with **\@**. like **myownemail\@yahoo.com**.